# How to say "What does it have to do with you" in German?

Tags: english-to-german, idiom

How do native German speakers say sentences such as:

> - "What does it have to do with you?"
> - "It has nothing to do with you."
> - "It's none of your business."

Comment: *Was hat das mit dir zu tun?* *Das hat nichts mit dir zu tun.* *Das geht dich nichts an!* - These are quite common expressions in everyday German. However, everything depends on context. Please give examples of concrete situations where you want to use such sentences.

Comment: PS  Please be aware that *Was hat das mit dir zu tun* has quite a different meaning and usage than *Das geht dich nichts an*. I don't know if your English phrases are pragmatic synonyms. The German phrases are not! A rough synonym of *Das geht dich nichts an* would be *Was hast du damit zu tun!*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The protypic way to express this is

> Das geht dich nichts an.

Besides that, there are a lot of other ways to express this:

> Warum mischst du dich hier ein?
>
> Warum hängst du dich hier rein?
>
> Misch dich nicht in fremde Angelegenheiten.
>
> Misch dich nicht in Sachen, die dich nichts angehen.
>
> Was hast du damit zu schaffen?
>
> Was geht dich das an?

Very formal, official:

> Das liegt außerhalb Ihres Zuständigkeitsbereichs.

Rather informal / colloquial:

> Das ist nicht dein Tanzbereich. (literal translation: *That's not your dancing area.*)
>
> Kümmer dich um deinen eignen Kram.
>
> Das ist nicht dein Bier.

Informal / angry:

> Kümmer dich um deinen eignen Scheiß.
>
> Halt du dich da raus!

Rather old:

> Was kümmert's dich?
>
> Was schert's dich?

A proverb goes like:

> Ein jeder kehre vor seiner eigenen Tür.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1)</sup> Variation in verse: *Ein jeder kehr' vor seinem Tor, da hat er Dreck genug davor.*

Comment: Is *"Was hat das mit dir zu tun?"* an anglicism?

Comment: I don't know, but I would say, probably not. I wouldn't consider it typical, either. I think, _A hat nichts mit B zu tun_ is more used in the sense of _A is not related to B_

Comment: Grob wäre auch noch: *Halt du dich da raus!*

Comment: Sehr förmlich noch: *Das liegt außerhalb Ihres Zuständigkeitsbereichs!*

Comment: @LangLangC  Right, the problem with *Was hat das mit dir zu tun* is that it has a completely different use-case. It is not a statement such as "This is none of your business", rather a mere direct question. When reading the question I even did not realize that the OP intended to say something like *Das geht dich nichts an*. Well... therefore I asked for context.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Is the phrase in Q a "mere statement"? Just a hunch. Use case what ever; but it feels a bit weird. --Then Q title is a question and body starts with one as well. It's unclear to me whether both are used in the same way rhetorically or one is an explanation for another.

Comment: @LangLangC  Exactly. We would need context here, e.g. real-life situations where the phrases would be used.

Comment: To add one more colloquial expression: *Das ist nicht dein Bier*

Comment: Because there were some good additions in the comments and there might be others, I turned my answer into a community wiki.

Comment: @LangLangC tbh I don't think I ever hears "Was hat das mit dir zu tun?" it's semantically the same as "Was geht dich das an?", and that is a phrase thats atually used

Comment: To be precise, the demand "Kümmere Dich um Deinen eigenen Kram!" is the equivalent of the English (American?) saying "Mind your own business!"